In an infinite square grid of resistors, why isn't current distributed equally at adjacent node of current injection?
Consider an infinite square grid of resistors, where a current of magnitude $i$ is injected at a particular node, and withdrawn at infinity. At that node, the current would split equally in the four paths.

At the adjacent node, it would redistribute into three paths. Since there are infinite resistors in the three possible directions of current from the connecting nodes, and the arrangement of resistors in all three paths is same, current should be distributed symmetrically here too. However, this is not the case according to Wang and Ricardo's Competitive Physics Vol 2: (Node $X$ is the node where current is injected and $Y$ is the node immediately to the right of $X$)

Let’s say we inject $1 \,\text{A}$ of current into node X and withdraw it from infinity again, it is true that $\frac{1}{2}\,\text{A}$ of current will flow directly from node $X$ to node $Y$ but we cannot conclude that $\frac{1}{12}\,\text{A}$ of current flows from node $Y$ to the node above $Y$. This is due to the limited symmetry of the grid. The node above $Y$ is symmetrical to the node below $Y$ but not to the node on the right of $Y$ in this sub-system. Thus, it is almost impossible to invoke symmetrical arguments in this case.

Why exactly are they not symmetrical?

I'll presume X is on the left (injection point) and Y is the other node to the right of X that you have highlighted. Is it clear to you that the node to the right of Y is different from the node up or down from Y?

@JonCuster yes, node X is injection point and node Y is adjacent of X. The nodes above/below and at right of Y are different relative to the current source, but the resistors connected to those nodes are arranged in the same way.

@brainfreeze Because the "forward" direction is not symmetry equivalent to the left and right directions. So we can't use symmetry alone to say that all 3 are equal. The most that symmetry can say is that the left and right must be equal.

@VincentThacker why is the forward direction not symmetric to the left and right directions, if the possible paths of the current that reaches those nodes are identical?

@brainfreeze The only symmetry operation you can perform is reflection about XY, which shows that left and right are equal. There is no symmetry operation that permutes all three directions. The entire grid has a fourfold rotational symmetry about X. There is no a priori reason why they must be equal. Note that this does not disprove equality. It just means that the symmetry doesn't imply equality.

@VincentThacker this is written in the book I mentioned:
When determining the equivalent resistance of a network of resistors with
respect to two terminals, one may identify symmetrical paths from a
starting terminal to an ending terminal and correspondingly, abuse such
symmetry. If you were a charge at the starting node, some paths to a
terminal node look indistinguishable from your perspective. You are equally
likely to take any of the paths, analogous to how identical currents flow
through corresponding segments along those paths.
Aren't the paths X-Y-Node above or right identical?

@brainfreeze Why do you think they are equal? One involves a 90-degree turn and the other does not. Like I said there is no permutation that switches the two while leaving the setup invariant. You need to clarify your reasoning.

@VincentThacker so, the fact that there is an equal amount of resistors connecting the nodes, and the paths after reaching the nodes are identical is an insufficient condition for equal current to flow through them; for that you need to be able to rotate/reflect the circuit to get the identical circuit with the paths permuted around? I suppose that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

@brainfreeze I have posted it as an answer.

The fact that the points have equal resistances between them is clearly not sufficient for them to be equivalent to each other. The equivalence depends on the entire circuit. This is true even in finite circuits. It should not be difficult to convince yourself that this would be absurd if true (just consider the case of a Wheatstone bridge). The most you can do here is reflection about $XY$, which shows that the currents to the left and right are equal. There is no symmetry operation that switches the forward and side directions while leaving the setup invariant. Your setup has 4-fold rotational symmetry about $X$ and four mirror lines passing through $X$. Note that this does not disprove equality; it just means that the symmetry doesn't imply it.
